# How can I overwrite an other Excel-file without the Dialog "Really want to overwrite" in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, excel

How can I save an Excel-file, which I'd edit with VB.NE, to a file, which already exists? Evertime there is a dialog: File already exists. Do you really want to overwrite? YES|NO|Abort

How can I overwrite without this dialog?

Comment: Please show us the code you are using! (The relevant section thereof, i.e., the part where you do the save operation.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should have a look at setting

```
DisplayAlerts=false
```

[Application.DisplayAlerts Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._application.displayalerts(office.11).aspx)

> Set this property to False if you
>   don’t want to be disturbed by prompts
>   and alert messages while a program is
>   running; any time a message requires a
>   response, Microsoft Excel chooses the
>   default response.

Just remember to reset it to true once you are done.

We currently do it as follows

```
object m_objOpt = Missing.Value;
m_Workbook.Application.DisplayAlerts = false;
m_Workbook.SaveAs(  fileName, m_objOpt, m_objOpt, 
                    m_objOpt, m_objOpt, m_objOpt, 
                    XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, 
                    XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges, 
                    m_objOpt, m_objOpt, m_objOpt, m_objOpt);
```

Comment: The dialog now doesn't pop up. But no, the application doesn't save the file.

Comment: I try to do it like you.. but there is an exception:
HRESULT : 0x800A03EC

Answer (score 2):

There is a property within the `SaveFileDialog` class, called `OverwritePrompt`, set that to false.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't use a SaveFileDialog. I close my excel application.

Comment: @elr: Ahhh... You should have said that in the question...and I run the risk of getting downvoted now as a result....are you using Excel COM Interop? Put that in your question also!

Answer (score 2):

> ```
>  Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
>  Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet
>  Dim misValue As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value
> ```

```
 xlWorkBook.SaveAs(<YourFileName>, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue,   misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue)
 xlWorkBook.Close(True, misValue, misValue)
```

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you try to delete the file first, before overwriting it?

Comment: If there isn't any other way.. I will choose this.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem setting the third parameter of xlApp.Workbooks.Open to false when you create the workbook. That is the readonly argument and if it is set to true it will ask for saving file.

```
Sub ExcelMacroExec2()
    Dim xlApp, xlBook

    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False

    Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\A\myFile.xlsm", 0, False)
    xlApp.Run "Macro1"   

    xlApp.Save 
    xlBook.Close false
    xlApp.Quit   

    Set xlApp = Nothing
    set xlBook = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this issue by using the Object.Save() method instead.  I tried to use the SaveAs method even with the DisplayAlerts = $false but it still kept giving me the overwrite warning.

Code Snippet Below:

```
# Create an Object Excel.Application using Com interface
$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
# Disable the 'visible' property so the document won't open in excel
$objExcel.Visible = $true
# Override warning messages about existing file
$objExcel.DisplayAlerts = $false
# Open the Excel file and save it in $WorkBook
$WorkBook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open($FilePath)
# Load the WorkSheet 'BuildSpecs'
$WorkSheet = $WorkBook.sheets.item($SheetName)
# Pause execution to allow data refresh to occur (about 5 minutes to be safe)
Start-Sleep -s 300
# Now the Save the file After Refreshing (need to add a pause for about 5 minutes)
$WorkBook.Save()
# Wait while saving before closing excel object
Start-Sleep -s 30
# Now close the workbook
```

Answer (score 0):

Dialog box avoided with (Application.DisplayAlerts = False) before saving command and (Application.DisplayAlerts = True) after:

```
Workbooks.Open "C:\XML\baseline\RTWP\Analisis.xlsb"
Windows("Analisis.xlsb").Activate
Sheets("Data").Select
Cells.Select
Selection.ClearContents
Workbooks.Open "C:\XML\baseline\RTWP\output\totemplate.csv"
Windows("totemplate.csv").Activate
Sheets("totemplate").Select
Cells.Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("Analisis.xlsb").Activate
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:="C:\XML\baseline\RTWP\Analisis.xlsb", FileFormat:=xlExcel12, CreateBackup:=False
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
Windows("totemplate.csv").Activate
ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
```