# Avoiding "Microsoft Excel" prompt

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, excel

I'm writing the following bits of code for a SaveFile Dialog box in Visual Basic 2010.NET. The code works well as the XLSX file is created and opens in Microsoft Excel. However, the problem that I am having is that if the program overwrites a file, the user is getting two prompts. One prompt is from the program's own SaveFile dialog confirming the choice. The other is from Microsoft Excel asking you the same. It's as if the program is running in the background.

Does anyone know how I can write this code to save the file as an Excel file?

```
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Public Class Frm1
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim misValue As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value

    Dim rowcounter As Integer = 1


    xlApp = New Excel.Application
    xlApp.Visible = False
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue)
    xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    xlWorkSheet.Cells(rowcounter, rowcounter) = "Something goes here."

    xlWorkSheet.SaveAs(SaveXLS.FileName)

    xlWorkBook.Close()
    xlApp.Quit()
End Class
```

Comment: I can't test it at the moment but I'm pretty sure it's xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False

Comment: @jesse you probably should have posted this as the answer...

Comment: @brettdj, probably but I hate posting as an answer unless I can test it.

Comment: @Jesse I agre - I always test answers where I can. I posted my comment partly as in a situation like this it would be a good outcome if the asker gave credit to the first answer, even if it was provided initially as a comment

Comment: I wouldn't mind giving the check and an upvote if it was posted an answer. Even if it wasn't tested, it's normally up to the poster (aka me) to test answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want `DisplayAlerts=false`. Take a look at the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2243995/how-can-i-overwrite-an-other-excel-file-without-the-dialog-really-want-to-overw).