# Duplicate "already exists" dialogs when I use SaveFileDialog and Excel.SaveAs

Tags: .net, excel-interop, savefiledialog

I am programmatically creating an Excel file with the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` framework.  When it comes time to save, I want to give the user the choice of naming and save location, so I am using `System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog`. Everything works well, except when the user chooses a filename which already exists, then both `SaveFileDialog.ShowDialog()` and `Excel.Application.SaveAs()` put up "This file already exists - are you sure you want to overwrite?" warnings, and of course 2 are not needed. I can't see a way to suppress either of them. What is the best way to fix this?

Comment: See this similar answer about DisplayAlerts:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2243995/how-can-i-overwrite-an-other-excel-file-without-the-dialog-really-want-to-overw

Comment: @BradNabholz - this was the answer I was looking for, setting `myExcelApp.Application.DisplayAlerts = false`. If you would like to put this as an answer I will give you credit for it.

Answer (score 0):

It may satisfy your requirement.

```
        try
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application my_app = null;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook my_book = null;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet my_sheet = null;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range rng = null;
            object missing = Type.Missing;

            my_app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            my_book = my_app.Workbooks.Add(missing);
            my_sheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)my_book.ActiveSheet;

            rng = my_sheet.get_Range("A1", missing);
            rng.Value2 = "Welcome Man";

            SaveFileDialog s = new SaveFileDialog();
            s.ShowDialog();

            if (s.OverwritePrompt)
            {
                my_book.SaveCopyAs(s.FileName);
                my_book.Close(false, s.FileName, missing);

            }
            else
            {
                my_app.Save(s.FileName);
                my_book.Close(true, s.FileName, missing);
            }

        }
        catch
        {

        }
```

Comment: There is no method `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application.Save()`, and `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook.Save()` has no overload which takes 1 arg.

Comment: i am using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel version 12.0.0.0,their Save() and saveCopyAs() methods takes file name as their parameters.