# How can I make it to automatically 'rewrite' the .xlsx file I'm trying to save?

Tags: excel, vb.net-2010

So, I have the following code to save the highscores into an excel file, it works, I only have one problem, it always asks if I want to rewrite the existing xlsx file, how can I make it to say automatically yes to it, or is there other way to save the xlsx file so it doesn't ask this question?

```
Imports EXC = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Private Sub highscoreSave()
    Dim app As EXC.Application
    Dim ws As EXC.Worksheet, wb As EXC.Workbook
    app = New EXC.Application()
    app.Visible = False
    wb = app.Workbooks.Open(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath.ToString & "\highscore.xlsx")
    ws = wb.Worksheets(1)
    For index As Integer = 1 To 11
        ws.Cells(index, 1).Value = lst_name(index - 1)
        ws.Cells(index, 2).Value = lst_score(index - 1)
    Next
    wb.Save()
    wb.Close()
    app.Quit()
End Sub
```

Comment: take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2243995/how-can-i-overwrite-an-other-excel-file-without-the-dialog-really-want-to-overw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To suppress messages to the user use:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
```

Comment: I tried 
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
It tells me, that's not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.Application'
And I tried
    EXC.Application.DisplayAlerts() = False
Which says, 'Reference to a non-shared member requires an object frame'.

And on the other hand would surpressing the message make it save the changes and change the file? (It says, It already exist, and if I wish to change the existing file /in the message/)

Comment: Oh, I mistook your problem for a VBA one, my bad

Comment: I probably wasn't so clear in the tagging, neither in the text, english is not my native language, I'm sorry for that.

Comment: @brettdj  He was apparently helped with the comment under the OP, and wanted to close the question. I could include the link in this answer, but than the answer will still be kind of minimal...

Answer (score 0):

Use

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

but don't forget to turn them back on before you exit your procedure...

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Comment: /This is a copy from my other comment, since K_B and You told me the same answer./ I tried Application.DisplayAlerts = False It tells me, that's not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.Application' And I tried EXC.Application.DisplayAlerts() = False Which says, 'Reference to a non-shared member requires an object frame'. And on the other hand would surpressing the message make it save the changes and change the file? (It says, It already exist, and if I wish to change the existing file /in the message/)